# Azure Bicep - creating a Key Vault secret in a pre-existing Azure Key Vault

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, azure-bicep

I've seen plenty of Bicep examples where a resource is provisioned and outputs a Key Vault secret to a Key Vault that is also provisioned at the same time of the run.

But what about Bicep code that creates a resource and outputs a Key vault secret into a previously provisioned/pre-existing Key Vault (like a shared Key vault) ?

I'm a Terraform person and would normally use a "data" reference to do this

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried to just reference the Key Vault using `existing`? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/existing-resource

Comment: described here https://ochzhen.com/blog/key-vault-and-secrets-azure-bicep

Comment: Thanks @silent that 2nd link is perfect

Comment: happy to hear it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define key vault with `existing` keyword and set it as `parent` of the keyvault/secrets resources.

However you need to make sure that module with those secrets’ definitions is targeting (the `scope` Property of the module) the resource group that keyvault is in.